# Android database : issue when binding parameters using selectionArgs

Tags: android, database

It seems that the `selectionArgs` has not been bind correctly but i could not spot any error here.

- This will return 2 result and that
  is correct

  ```
  String sql = "SELECT * FROM tblEvent_extDes WHERE (eguid = 196 ) ";
  c = epgDB.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {});
  ```
- This will not return any result.
  Why??

  ```
   String sql = "SELECT * FROM tblEvent_extDes WHERE (eguid = ? ) ";
   c = epgDB.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {"196"});
  ```

EDIT:
And this works...

```
 sql = "SELECT rowid * FROM tblEvent_extDes WHERE eguid = " +  String.valueOf(196);
 // could replace 196 with a variable
```

Comment: I believe you do not hardcode new String[] {"196"}, but use some variable. Did you tried to check if variable value correct?

Comment: I am trying to simply the problem. Even with the hardcode value, it returns empty cursor.

Comment: And the variable value is correct,

Comment: Your edit as a workaround, you'll experince difficulties with params count grater than 1. I will be hardly-editable mess.

Comment: try using this way: String[] argList = new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }; return mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sqlStatement, argList);

Comment: @woodsy your proposal is same as approach 2 as I listed

Comment: I can confirm this issue, but only in Android API <= 10 AKA Gingerbread or earleir. SelectionArgs work when I test with Android 4.0+ (I have not tested this in Honeycomb yet). For devices running Android Gingerbread or below, I null the selectionArgs and concatenate the query variables by hand (e.g. "id = 12345")

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem, It might be a conversion issue, however I couldn't see how to fix this except if you use :
`String sql = "SELECT * FROM tblEvent_extDes WHERE (eguid = " + 196 + " ) ";`

that of corse is usable only if 196 is not user input ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm what you see and this is how I handle it;

```
String selection = null;
String[] selectionArgs = null;
if(API_LEVEL <= 10){
    //Make sure that you handle String variables accordingly. 
    //This assumes an int or long value.
    selection = "id = " + variableId; 
    selectionArgs = null;
}else{ //Honeycomb/ICS/Jellybean
    selection = "id = ?";
    selectionArgs = new String[]{variableId});
}
//Query Code Here...
```

I have not found any other way to deal with this issue. I hope this helps you or anyone else.